# What is the excel formula I should use if I want to count and/or average based on having a record meeting multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to count the number of customer ids (Left Column) that completed both a test drive and filled out a credit application (3rd Column from Left).

What formula should I use?

[image]

Comment: Can't you do this with a `=CountIf()` or a `=CountIfS()` function?

Comment: I think you would need an array formula, a helper column, or a UDF for this...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this UDF:

```
Function GetMultipleCriteriaCount(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, crit1 As String, crit2 As String)

    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In rng1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng1, cell.Value, rng2, crit1) > 0 And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng1, cell.Value, rng2, crit2) > 0 Then
            GetMultipleCriteriaCount = GetMultipleCriteriaCount + 1
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            GetMultipleCriteriaCount = GetMultipleCriteriaCount / 2
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
        
End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: All I need to do is drop this in the VB Editor?